# What is the source of Hannah Arendt's quote about Les Mots by Sartre?

Tags: quote-source, hannah-arendt

Earlier this year, Samantha Rose Hill, who has been working on a book about Hannah Arendt, [tweeted](https://twitter.com/Samantharhill/status/1375784742130434052),

> "I just finished reading Sartre's Les Mots—and was so disgusted that I was almost tempted to review this piece of highly complicated lying."
> Hannah Arendt on Jean-Paul Sartre:
> "(…) It reminds me of what I heard recent scholarship has unearthed about Rousseau—he did *not* have five children at the orphanage for the simple reason that he was impotent, which I think is most likely. Sartre's case is precisely the same: You tell seemingly outrageous 'truths' with a great show of sincerity in order to hide the better what actually happened. I am wondering how he will explain or tell his sort of 'truth' with respect to the unpleasant fact that he did not participate in the resistance, in fact never lifted a finger. (…)"

(The bottom part of the above quote is transcribed from an image embedded in the tweet.)

The tone of the comment suggests that this is from a letter, possibly from Arendt's correspondence with [Mary McCarthy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_McCarthy_(author)), who later became Arendt's literary executor. Can the above quote be dated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it can be dated:

The quote comes from Arendt's letter to McCarthy of Christmas 1964 and can be found on [page 172 of their published correspondence 'Between Friends'](https://archive.org/details/betweenfriendsco00aren/page/172/mode/2up), published by Harcourt Brace in 1995.